N8N no detecta variable de entorno en Jelastic con JPS
Estoy intentando implementar n8n con un manifiesto JPS, pero tengo el problema de que n8n no detecta la variable de entorno DB_POSTGRESDB_HOST y necesito pasar a esa variable la ip del nodo postgres con ${nodes.sqldb[0].address } Solo funciona cuando lo he implementado y agregado manualmente esa variable y su valor desde la interfaz gráfica pero no he podido pasarle esa variable desde el JPS, ni siquiera escribiendo una IP aleatoria para ver si la detecta.
¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe?
Muchas gracias.
type: install
id: n8n-workflow
version: 1.0
name: n8n Workflow Automation
homepage: https://n8n.io/
logo: https://asset.brandfetch.io/idO6_6uqJ9/id-H5HD3pX.png?updated=1655217178680
globals:
  db_user: n8n-${fn.random(1000)}
  db_pswd: ${fn.password}
  encryption_key: n8n${fn.password}
targetRegions:
  type: [ vz.*, pcs.* ]
categories:
  - apps/automation
  - apps/popular

onBeforeInit: |
  import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
  import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;

  var client = new HttpClient(),
      getMethod,
      response,
      status,
      resp,
      url;
  
  url = "https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/n8nio/n8n/tags";
  getMethod = new GetMethod(url);
  status = client.executeMethod(getMethod);
  resp = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
  resp = JSON.parse(resp);
  tags = resp.results;

  var ver = {};
  var def = "latest";
  var tag;

  for (var i = 0, n = tags.length; i < n; i++) {
      tag = tags[i].name;
      if (tag) {
          ver[tag] = tag;
          def = tag;
      }
  }

  return {
      result: 0,
      settings: {
          fields: [{
              name: "version",
              caption: "n8n Version",
              type: "list",
              values: ver,
              "default": def
          }]
      }
  };

ssl: true

nodes:
- nodeType: nginx
  displayName: Load Balancer
  cloudlets: 16
  nodeGroup: bl
- image: n8nio/n8n:${settings.version}
  displayName: n8n
  cloudlets: 16
  nodeGroup: cp
  links: sqldb:db
  startServiceOnCreation: true
  env:
    N8N_BASIC_AUTH_ACTIVE: true
    N8N_BASIC_AUTH_USER: ${globals.db_user}
    N8N_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD: ${globals.db_pswd}
    WEBHOOK_TUNNEL_URL: ${env.url}
    N8N_ENCRYPTION_KEY: ${globals.encryption_key}
    DB_TYPE: postgresdb
    DB_POSTGRESDB_DATABASE: n8n
    DB_POSTGRESDB_HOST: ${nodes.sqldb[0].address}
    DB_POSTGRESDB_PORT: 5432
    DB_POSTGRESDB_USER: ${globals.db_user}
    DB_POSTGRESDB_PASSWORD: ${globals.db_pswd}
- image: postgres:16.2
  cloudlets: 16
  nodeGroup: sqldb
  displayName: PostgreSQL DB
  env:
    POSTGRES_USER: ${globals.db_user}
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${globals.db_pswd}
    POSTGRES_DB: n8n

onInstall:
  - if ('${env.protocol}' == 'https'):
      cmd[bl]: |-
        CONF_FILE="/etc/nginx/nginx-jelastic.conf"
        sed -i ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\\(location \\/ {\\)/\\1\\n\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\tif ($http_x_forwarded_proto = http) {\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\treturn 302 https:\\/\\/$host$request_uri;\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\terror_page  500 502 503 504 = @rescue;\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t}\\n/1' "$CONF_FILE"
        sed -i -r 's/(:80)\$ common;/:5678\$ common;/' "$CONF_FILE"
        sed -i -r 's/(server[[:space:]]+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(;)/\1:5678\2/g' "$CONF_FILE"
        sed -i -r 's/(server[[:space:]]+([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+))[[:space:]]*;/\1:5678;/' "$CONF_FILE"
        service nginx restart
      user: root
      

success: |-
  n8n Workflow Automation is ready to use. Please open [${env.url}](${env.url}) to configure your workflows.
  
  **Username:** ${globals.db_user}
  **Password:** ${globals.db_pswd}

